# write test case in jest for DOM

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to write unit testing in jest for the code below:

```
var checkallboxes = document.getElementsByName("rowSelectCheckBox");
for (var i = 0, n = checkallboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
  checkallboxes[i].checked = true;
}
```

How to write test code in jest?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and how the above snippet is used in your code.  Right now there isn't enough info to help.

Comment: I have multiple checkbox in a component. if user select some checkbox then i need to write code for unit testing.
As per snipped, variable checkallboxes contain selected checkbox value and after that loop will process.

Comment: Have you read [Vue's guide on unit testing](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html)?